# Where is the constructor String(int, int, char[]) defined?

Tags: java, string, constructor

I am trying to understand the implementation of [Integer](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html).toString(), which looks like this:

```
public static String toString(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return "-2147483648";
    int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i) + 1 : stringSize(i);
    char[] buf = new char[size];
    getChars(i, size, buf);
    return new String(0, size, buf);
}
```

And I ran into the last line, which doesn't look like any of the constructors in the [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class, except this one:

```
String(char value[], int offset, int count)
```

...except that this function is called with the char[] argument first, unlike how it is being used in Integer.toString(). I was under the impression that changing the order of arguments counted as a change in the signature of the method, and would be a different overwrite of the method.

Why does this work, or am I interpreting this incorrectly?

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of String. It probably has some package private stuff that wouldn't show up in the public javadoc.

Comment: But (1+) for checking the API and asking a thoughtful question.

Comment: Where are you seeing the alleged code? It's not [in Java 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/9d617cfd6717/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l397).

Comment: @Boann: It's in the [link](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html). openjdk-7, apparently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's using a package-private `String` constructor. It doesn't show up in the `String` Javadoc, because it's package-private.

If you check the [`String` source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html) on the same site, you'll see

```
  644       // Package private constructor which shares value array for speed.
  645       String(int offset, int count, char value[]) {
  646           this.value = value;
  647           this.offset = offset;
  648           this.count = count;
  649       }
```